# Cannot change the cipher key in Base64 Decoder

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, base64, des

I have a pre-written code which is used to cipher the given plain text or vice-versa .

The class has 3 methods, where in 2 methods can be used for encrypting and decrypting respectively.

```
public class SqlCipherUtil {

    private Cipher ecipher;
    private Cipher dcipher;

    public String encryptString(String pStrPlainText) {

        try {
            generateKey();
            byte[] utf8 = pStrPlainText.getBytes("UTF8");
            byte[] enc = this.ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
            return new BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return null;
    }

    public String decryptString(String pStrCipherText){

        try {
            generateKey();
            byte[] dec = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(pStrCipherText);
            byte[] utf8 = this.dcipher.doFinal(dec);
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to generate the encrypted key.
     */
    private void generateKey() {

        try {
            byte[] decodedStr = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer("rA/LUdBA/hA=");
            SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedStr, "DES");
            this.ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            this.dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
            this.ecipher.init(1, key);
            this.dcipher.init(2, key);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

The key present in the class cannot be changed to any other key
in line `byte[] decodedStr = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer("rA/LUdBA/hA=");`, 
and it is giving an exception.

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: Invalid key length: 9 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineGetKeySize(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.b(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.a(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(DashoA13*..)
```

I tried out the below code, and I am getting exactly 8 bytes in the array.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        byte[] decodedStr = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer("rA/LUdBA/hA=");

        for(byte b : decodedStr){
            System.out.print(b);
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

}
```

Any other combination of the key will make the byte array size more than 8 or less than 7.

What is the concept behind getting the byte array size 8 ?

What should be done to use custom key combination or our custom generated keys ?

Please answer Both the questions.

Comment: That initialization code works for me... are you *sure* you've got exactly that code?

Comment: The code works fine for me if the key is only "rA/LUdBA/hA=".
If we vary the key I am getting an exception.

Try it out yourself, change the key to a different key, 
In a main program try Invoking 

new SqlCipherUtil().encryptString("jon-skeet");

You will get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your target is encode and decode the string, Use `Base64`.

```
    public class PasswordCodecHandler {
        Base64 codec = null;

        public PasswordCodecHandler() {
            codec = new Base64();
        }

        public String encode(String password) {
            byte[] temp;
            String encodedPassword = null;
            temp = codec.encode(password.getBytes());
            encodedPassword = new String(temp);
            return encodedPassword;
        }

        public String decode(byte[] encodedPassword) {
            byte[] temp;
            String decodedPassword;
            temp = codec.decode(encodedPassword);
            decodedPassword = new String(temp);
            return decodedPassword;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PasswordCodecHandler passwordCodecHandler = new PasswordCodecHandler();
            String s1 = passwordCodecHandler.encode("password");
            System.out.println(s1);

            String s2 = passwordCodecHandler.encode("admin");
            System.out.println(s2);

            String s3 = passwordCodecHandler.encode("administrator");
            System.out.println(s3);

            String s4 = passwordCodecHandler.encode("123456");
            System.out.println(s4);

        }
    }
```

For other data type : it can be `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` based on the your memory allocation size

```
    /* Download apache common-io.xxx. jar*/

    public class CodecHandler {
        Base64 codec = null;

        public CodecHandler() {
            codec = new Base64();
        }

        public byte[] encode(byte[] decoded) {
            return codec.encode(decoded);
        }

        public byte[] decode(byte[] encoded) {
            return codec.decode(encoded);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            File file = new File("D:/Test.mp4");
            byte[] fileByteArray = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
            CodecHandler codecHandler = new CodecHandler();
            byte[] encoded = codecHandler.encode(fileByteArray);
            System.out.println("Byte Size : " + encoded.length);
            byte[] decode = codecHandler.decode(encoded);
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("C:/Test.mp4"), decode);


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Any other combination of the key will make the byte array size more
>   than 8 or less than 7.

I doubt that. You're probably adding or removing the wrong characters; or at the wrong position. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

And yes 9 bytes is not a valid key length for DES. You could simply shorten it to the proper length. You do get 9 bytes because your base64 string is 3x4 characters long which will be decoded to 3x3 = 9 characters. Trim the output.

> What is the concept behind getting the byte array size 8 ?

DES uses 56 Bit Keys. 8 Bytes = 64 Bit, so sufficient bits for the key.

> What should be done to use custom key combination or our custom generated keys ?

Let the user enter a key that has at least 7 characters (56 Bit).
I really don't see why you use base64 in this sample at all - probably just because you copied it from somewhere? You just need a few random bytes. The common way to get those are to build a hash from any input the user gives and use bytes from that hash.

Comment: The code works fine for me if the key is only "rA/LUdBA/hA=". If i vary the key I am getting an exception. Try it out yourself, change the key to a different key, In a main program try Invoking 
new SqlCipherUtil().encryptString("JoSO");

Comment: DES uses a 8-byte key but ignores the lsb of each byte, orriginally the lsb was used for parity.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the concept behind getting the byte array size 8?

Your new, based-64–encoded key must be 12 characters long, ending with one, and only one, `=` character.

In base-64, the character `=` is a padding character, and it can only appear at the end of the encoded string. Base-64 encoding outputs a block of 4 characters from each input block of 3 bytes. If the input length is not a multiple of 3, the last block is padded.

In the encoded key, "rA/LUdBA/hA=", there are 12 characters, which can encode 9 bytes. But the last character is padding, which means the last byte should be ignored, leaving 8 bytes.

> What should be done to use custom key combination or our custom generated keys?

First, you shouldn't use DES. It's too weak and insecure. But in general, the correct process for generating a secure key in Java is to use the [`KeyGenerator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/KeyGenerator.html) class. For (insecure) DES, you can generate a key and encode it with base-64 like this:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

…

KeyGenerator gen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
gen.init(56);
SecretKey secret = gen.generateKey();
String b64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getEncoded());
System.out.println(b64);
```

To use the key, decode it like this:

```
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeySpec;

…

SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(b64), "DES");
```